# How to reference a type in itself?

Tags: typescript

I have this typescript code:

```
type CreateUserFields = {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  confirmPassword: string;
  email: string;
  // Other fields...
};

export const connectionInfoStepFieldNames: (keyof CreateUserFields)[] = [
  'username',
  'password',
  'confirmPassword',
] as const

export type ConnectionInfoStepFields = Pick<CreateUserFields, (typeof connectionInfoStepFieldNames)[number]>
```

The problem is that `ConnectionInfoStepFields` is equal to all the fields that were defined In `CreateUserFields`, where I want it to only `Pick` the fields that I defined inside my `connectionInfoStepFieldNames` array.

The cause of this problem is this portion of the code: `: (keyof CreateUserFields)[]`

when I remove it, the problem goes away, but I want to keep it, so that I keep getting type checking on the `connectionInfoStepFieldNames` array while I am writing new strings inside of it, so that I don't go out of the scope of the keys defined in `CreateUserFields`

I thought this would solve it but it did not work:

```
export const connectionInfoStepFieldNames: ConnectionInfoStepFields[] = [
  'username',
  'password',
  'confirmPassword',
] as const
```

It gave me this error:

```
connectionInfoStepFieldNames' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation. 2502
```

In simple words, `ConnectionInfoStepFields` should be equal to:

```
'username' | 'password' | 'confirmPassword'
```

these are exactly the `connectionInfoStepFieldNames` array value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `satisfies` operator solves this exact problem. You can remove the type annotation and instead do this:

```
export const connectionInfoStepFieldNames = [
  'username',
  'password',
  'confirmPassword',
] satisfies (keyof CreateUserFields)[];
```

This let's you use `typeof` on `connectionInfoStepFieldNames` to get its specific type (i.e., `('username' | 'password' | 'confirmPassword')[]`) as you desired, while the `satisfies (keyof CreateUserFields)[]` essentially asks TypeScript if `connectionInfoStepFieldNames` actually satisfies `(keyof CreateUserFields)[]`. If you add 'hello' to the array, it will generate an error saying "*Type '"hello"' is not assignable to type 'keyof CreateUserFields'.*"

You can read the documentation here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html